# java thread dispatching issue

Tags: java, multithreading

I have defined ThreadA and ThreadB as the following and in the main() method, I just do

```
 new ThreadA().start();  new ThreadB().start();
```

So I see interleaved print of char "A" and "B", that makes sense to me. But I found out that no matter how many times that I run the program, "A" is always printed first. Is this just  coincidence or because that I called A's start() first?

Also, once I introduce some delay in A's run() before the for loop, or I start to call B's run() first, then I see B is printed first.

Please help me in understanding this.
Thanks.

```
class ThreadA extends Thread
{ 
   @Override
    public void run() {

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        for (int i =0;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("A");
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(;;)
            {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() -start > 100)
                    break;
            }
        }

    }
}

class ThreadB extends Thread
{


    @Override
    public void run() {

        for (int i =0;i<10;i++)
        {
            System.out.println("B");
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            for(;;)
            {
                if (System.currentTimeMillis() -start > 100)
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It may be because A started few milliseconds ahead of B (but not guaranteed always because OS controls which thread should go first), but interleaving can never be guaranteed (unless you code the thread dependency).

Comment: Chances are that `new ThreadB()` takes enough time to complete that the first thread already is running before the second thread gets started.  But the one thing you can be certain of when you're trying to understand how the thread executions are interleaved is that nothing is certain.  It's not guaranteed to be predictable, and it's not guaranteed to be _unpredictable_.

Comment: @jameslarge You are absolutely right. When the main thread is busy newing TheadB, it lost the CPU and threadA gets the chance to execute. After I changed to code to `ThreadA tA= new ThreadA(); ThreadB tB= new ThreadB(); tA.start(); tB.start()`, I occasianlly see B was printed ahead of A.